# Вывести неповторяющиеся записи из таблицы умножения

Tags: java

Я начал изучать Java. Наткнулся в интернете на задачу:

> Для проверки остаточных знаний учеников после летних каникул, учитель
> младших классов решил начинать каждый урок с того, чтобы задавать
> каждому ученику пример из таблицы умножения, но в классе 15 человек, а
> примеры среди них не должны повторяться. В помощь учителю напишите
> программу, которая будет выводить на экран 15 случайных примеров из
> таблицы умножения (от 2×2 до 9×9, потому что задания по умножению на 1
> и на 10 — слишком просты). При этом среди 15 примеров не должно быть
> повторяющихся (примеры 2×3 и 3×2 и им подобные пары считать
> повторяющимися).

Моё решение такое:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tasksArray = tasksArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            System.out.println(tasksArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static String[] tasksArray() {
        String[] tasksArray = new String[36];
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 9; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 9; j++) {
                tasksArray[n] = i + " × " + j + " = ?";
                n++;
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(tasksArray));
        return tasksArray;
    }
}
```

Я так и не додумался самостоятельно, как перемешивать массив. Но зато узнал о Collections.shuffle.
Мой вопрос: как бы решили такую задачи опытные программисты? Интересует сам подход.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/7485582

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 2;
        int max = 9;
        int size = 15;
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        while (set.size() < size + 1) {
            // generate first element
            int first = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
            // generate second element
            int second = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
            // validate first*second and second*first
            if (!set.contains(first + " * " + second) && (!set.contains(second + " * " + first))) {
                set.add(first + " * " + second);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Жесть) Пришлось гуглить, чтобы разобраться) спасибо)

Comment: я бы даже упростил, если слева всегда наименьщее число то можно сразу добавлять в коллекцию:  int first = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
             // generate second element
             int second = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
             String result=first<second ? first + " * " + second : second + " * " + first;
             set.add(result)